# C++ Enum equivalent in Kotlin

Tags: enums, kotlin

The problem I am trying to solve:

I have a list of elements. The list can be large and there can be many of them. I would like to access them by index. For those indexes I would like to use words instead of numbers. I would also like this words to be strongly typed, so I cannot mix numbers with them.

I believe Kotlin enum is not good for this, since every enumeration is an object instance itself. I can use Int constants, but then I lose the type safety.

In c++ this problem is solved by an Enum. Enumerations can be casted to their underlying type (in compile time) to be used as indexes. At the same type the Enum is a type and if a function takes it as a parameter, the compiler won't allow passing integers in. The enumerations themselves are not objects themselves, so you can have as many as you like without any performance hit.

C++ code example to show what I am looking for:

```
string someArray[] = {"element 0", "element 1"};

enum class Index
{
    first = 0,
    second = 1,
};

string getElement(Index i)
{
    return someArray[(int)i];
}

void foo()
{
    auto element0 = getElement(Index::first);
    auto element1 = getElement(1);  // compile time error - parameter type mismatch
}
```

Comment: "I believe Kotlin enum is not good for this, since every enumeration is an object instance itself." Enums on the JVM are singleton instances, if you're worried about object creation, you only create one object instance for each value of the enum. Or did I misunderstand your point?

Comment: @zsmb13 Since I would use enums as index constants, there is no need to have singleton objects created. And there could be thousands of elements in the lists, so there could be thousands indexes. Seems like a needless overhead to have so many objects created.

Answer (score 2):

How about defining an enum and also an extension to index lists of the desired type with the enum elements? This way, you can limit the indexing capabilities only to lists of `Foo` if you need it. Otherwise, make the extension generic.

```
enum class Index { FIRST, SECOND }   
operator fun List<Foo>.get(index: Index) = get(index.ordinal)

// Usage:
val foo = listOfFoo[Index.FIRST]
```

<sup>Use `import com.example.Index.*` to reference the elements it as just `FIRST` and `SECOND`.</sup>

Or define a non-operator function that does not get confused with the operator:

```
fun List<Foo>.getElement(index: Index) = get(index.ordinal)

// Usage:
val foo = listOfFoo.getElement(Index.FIRST)
```

However, I don't think there's currently a solution that would allow you to both have pseudonyms for integers that are typed differently, and avoid having the instances for them at runtime (well, maybe a custom source transformation at compile time would). The concept that is closest to allowing this is [value types](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~jrose/values/values-0.html), but it is currently supported by neither JVM nor Kotlin.

Comment: I am specifically looking for a solution that does not create objects for constants. I guess such a solution is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Thousands of objects is really very little, but you could just use normal Kotlin enums and then use [Proguard](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard) to optimize them out. It does so by default but you may need to be careful configuring it and don't forget to test the application thoroughly afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

You have a comma behind second =1,

Remove that to this:

```
enum class Index
{
  first = 0,
  second = 1
};
```

Comment: This does not answer my question. Also there is nothing wrong with the comma.